# Animate right bottom to left up and not dissapear

Tags: javascript, css, html, jquery-animate

I want to animate a DIV since bottom right to left up, when height and width is 0px, then disappear and I don't see this box when I want to see the box in different axis(-x, y).

http://jsfiddle.net/ra04roza/

```
  $("button").click(function(){
    $("div").animate({
      height:'-=150px',
      width:'-=150px'
    });
  });
```

Comment: I want resize effect

Comment: If you resize with height<=0 and width<=0 of course its going to dissappear

Comment: Dude you got 3 answers doing 3 completely different things. If I were you I would reformat my question

Comment: First, you have to resize the div to see it again. http://jsfiddle.net/ra04roza/6/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this: (Though I have added new elements)

**HTML**

```
<button>Start Animation</button>
<div class = "div1" style="background:#98bf21;top:250px;left:250px;height:100px;width:100px;position:absolute;">
</div>

<div class = "div2" style="background:#98bf21;top:250px;left:250px;height:0px;width:0px;position:absolute;">
</div>
```

**jQuery**

```
$("button").click(function(){
    $(".div1").animate({
      height:'-=150px',
      width:'-=150px'
    }, 1000);

    $(".div2").animate({
      height:'+=100px',
      width:'+=100px',
      top: '-=100px',
      left: '-=100px'
    }, 1000);
  });
```

Fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/ra04roza/5/)

Comment: so what if you click start animation again? I dont think that is normal

Comment: thanks, I want this demo!, the second step when you resize a green box.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:-

<kbd>[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ra04roza/2/)</kbd>

Html:-

```
<button>Start Animation</button>
<div style="background:#98bf21;top:100%;right:0px;height:100px;width:100px;position:absolute;">
</div>
```

> ```
>   $("button").click(function(){
>     $("div").animate({
>       right:'100%',
>       top:0,
>       opacity:'0.5',
>
>     });
>   });
> ```

Comment: with this demo you move the box, and I want resize effect... since right bottom to left top.

Answer (score 0):

if i understand what you want to achieve you need to apply the callback function (what would happened when complete, aka [complete function](http://api.jquery.com/animate/#complete).

```
$("button").click(function(){
  $("div").animate({
    height:'-=150px',
    width:'-=150px'
  }, function(){
       $(this).css( {top: '1000px',
                     left: '800px' });
  });
});
```

you can see at your [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ra04roza/4/)